# Error with composer using Laravel for JWT

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, composer-php

following this guide: https://laravel-angular.io/docs/1/jwt-auth-install/ I've installed `tymon/jwt-auth:^1.0@dev` correctly. It's all okay but, when I run: `composer require irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard`, this error appears.

```
composer require irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard
Using version ^1.0 for irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard[dev-master, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.4] require illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard 1.0.x-dev is an alias of irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard ^1.0 -> satisfiable by irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard[v1.0.0, ..., 1.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

My PHP version is: 7.4.16;

My Laravel version is: 8.12;

My composer version is: 2.0.9.

I don't know what can I do. Thanks to all for the help!

**UPDATE:**

This is the error after run `composer require irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard  --ignore-platform-reqs`:

```
Using version ^1.0 for irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard[dev-master, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.4] require illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard 1.0.x-dev is an alias of irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard ^1.0 -> satisfiable by irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard[v1.0.0, ..., 1.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this package!
- The package doesn't have any tests
- It only has two files and using tymon/jwt-auth

Laravel already has support JWT -  it is using tymon/jwt-auth. Laravel already comes with jwt support

----
So you don't need this package you can copy over the files and add your own test.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport

Comment: Also have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: So using Laravel Sanctum I don't even need tymon/jwt-auth?

Comment: Exactly have a look at https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/composer.json its using https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt instead of tymon/jwt-auth

Comment: There is more info here on how your JS can consume the JWT https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need tymon/jwt-auth it is not even maintained and it is 5 years old...better try with this... https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/

Comment: I want to achieve a simple JWT Authentication. Thank you so much Ersin. I'll see Sanctum and Passport!

Comment: Thank you, I will also look at positronx.io/ and choose which one to use!

Comment: The doc is not  even maintained...you could try with https://medium.com/@eloufirhatim/laravel-angular-authentication-bee4100e5e33

Comment: As the error message tells you: `irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard`  requires Laravel v5. Why do you want to use such an outdated package?

Comment: I'll not use irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard any more. I'll use the packages reccomended by ohter guys. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

lcobucci/jwt is a framework-agnostic PHP library that allows you to issue, parse, and validate JSON Web Tokens based on the RFC 7519.

By running the following command you could install it.

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt
```

You can find more documentation of it here

https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase Will definitely do that